# Why does adding or removing a newline change the way this perl for loop functions?

Tags: perl, for-loop, newline

I'm starting to learn perl, using the [Wrox Beginning Perl available on perl.org](http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/) and have a question regarding a for loop example they provide in Chapter 3.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @count = (1..10);
for (reverse(@count)) {
        print "$_...\n";
        sleep 1;
}
print "Blast Off!\n"
```

This is the script they provide, and it works as expected. It displays a number followed by ... every second, waiting a second in between each number. When done, it displays `Blast Off!`

However if I remove the newline from the print statement, the behaviour changes. The script silently waits 10 seconds and then displays all 10 numbers and `Blash Off!` at once. Why the change?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @count = (1..10);
for (reverse(@count)) {
        print "$_...";
        sleep 1;
}
print "Blast Off!\n"
```

Comment: Output to STDOUT is buffered by default. Do "perldoc perlvar" and look for $|

Comment: For more fun try `print "$_... \r` ( after setting autoflush );

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perl is buffering the `print` output and the buffer isn't flushed until the newline. Alternatively, you can add `$| = 1` before your loop to tell Perl to flush the buffer between the print statements, thus giving you the expected output with the proper delay:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

$| = 1; #Add this line
my @count = (1..10);
for (reverse(@count)) {
        print "$_...";
        sleep 1;
}
print "Blast Off!\n"'
```

Comment: The way I did it, with the select statements, is safer if there is any other file interaction.

Comment: Even better, and more modern:
    use IO::Handle;
    STDOUT->autoflush(1);

Answer (score 4):

Standard output is line buffered.  It won't flush the buffer until it sees a newline.  You can correct this by adding the following line before the loop:

```
my $ofh = select(STDOUT); $| = 1; select $ofh;
```

Let's break that down:

`my $ofh = select(STDOUT);` - selects the STDOUT (standard output) as the current selected file handle, and stores whatever was the previous selected file handle in `$ofh`

`$| = 1;` - sets the current file handle (ie. STDOUT) to unbuffered.

`select $ofh;` - reselects whatever was the selected file handle before, so that if the code had selected a file handle other than STDOUT at some point, it will still be selected after this line of code is finished.

Comment: You should probably explain what the `select`s are for.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at the standard behavior of the line-oriented output of the C stdio library when writing to a terminal.

See [autoflush](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH) for perl details.

Answer (score 1):

A neater way than using select() to set the autoflush flag on STDOUT is to use IO::Handle (which has been included with the Perl core since version 5.004):

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush(1)
```